# How can I undo changes to gitlab badges

Tags: gitlab

I changed a badge in one of my company's repos but I messed up the url.  Now I can't find the old url.  Is there a way I can find the badge's old url?

This is easy in github via `git show HEAD~:README.md` since badge state and history is stored in the git repo, but I don't see where gitlab stores badge state.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no history or revert option for badge URLs. The only state is the current state. As soon as you change the badge URL, the old state is lost forever, unless you are self-hosting GitLab and perhaps you have access to logs or database backups...

You will just have to figure out the correct URL somehow. Maybe ask a colleague if they know what the previous URL was.

In the future, it may be good to know that you can [preview badges](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_badges.html#preview-a-badge-from-a-project) to make sure they are correct.